# Android spinner- weird ui issue

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I am using android spinner to show drop down options and i have customized its style and item style.
It works fine but on lollipop it shows shadow like shown in the screenshot.

[image: note 2]
[image: Nexus 5]
spinner style is extended from the appCompat as below

```
<style name="spinner_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
```

and setting these properties

```
   <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">7dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/margin_extra_large</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">@dimen/padding_basic_large</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/login_edit_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@color/app_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@color/app_background_color</item>
```

i am setting array adapter for spinner items as follow

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_ltdids,
           ids);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

Any idea why its showing shadow on lollipop?

Note: i am using appcompat_21

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36005643/2826147).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the popupBackground property and try, it should work!

Comment: you are a life saver (Y)