# app crashes when spinner is pressed inside popupwindow which is located in fragment

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-popupwindow

i have a fragment with a button. The button is pressed and if the user credentials entered match a valid user(the input fields ara being checked requests to rest api) a popupwindow is displayed with a spinner, a textview and an editext.

in volley `onresponse` `createPopUpWindow` method is called

### onResponse()

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_ERROR);
                        if (success.equals("true")){
                           errorresponseTtv.setText(jsonObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_ERROR_MSG));
                        }
                        else{
                           errorresponseTtv.setText("Success!:\n User-> " + jsonObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_USERNAME) + ", password-> " + jsonObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_PASSWORD) + ", email-> " + jsonObject.getString(AppConfig.TAG_EMAIL));
                            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_login, null);

                            createPopUpWindow(layout);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

createPopUpWindow()

```
private void createPopUpWindow(final View layout) {
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    true);
            firmSpnr = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.firmSpnr);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
            firmSpnr.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            popupWindow.update();
}
```

the popupWindow is displayed as it is expected but the problem occurs when i press the spinner.

The log message is `"Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImp"` is your activity running?
i have searched about any similar issues others have faced and i found out that i must defer showing the popup until after all the lifecycle methods are called. Can anyone provide a solution on how to fix the error?

**log error messages**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem, PID: 32577
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@421769f8 is not valid; is your activity running?
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:532)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1019)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:925)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:78)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:30)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:92)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:171)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:654)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropdownPopup.show(AppCompatSpinner.java:766)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:424)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-03 18:56:17.703 32577-32577/com.votingsystem.tsiro.votingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in OnResponse else condition

```
 layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createPopUpWindow(layout);
        }
    });
```

instead of createPopUpWindow(layout);

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not provide the expected outcome...still the same error..

Comment: can you post the complete log message ?

Comment: setting spinnermode attribute to dialog solves the problime but what if i would like to use the default mode (dropdown)?

Comment: can you try this edited answer and let me know whether this works or not

Comment: are you doing this in fragment's onCreate method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94123/discussion-between-tsiro-and-yashodhan-divakaran).

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue was reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202246

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This issue has been resolved.**

**Fixed a compatibility crash with AppCompatSpinner on API level 21 and below**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

Comment: Is this helpfull ?@tsiro